# Datawarehouse dealing with Bit datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

Just wondering what peoples thought's are when dealing with bit data type in the context of datawarehouse? Would it remain as Bit or would you convert the datatype to INT? what are the pitfalls when dealing with bit data type when its 0 = false and 1 is true.

I am using SSIS and having problems with the output looking like -1 when converting to int. But can it remain as bit? or is it good practise to change it to INT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it is best to use the appropriate data type for what you model. If something can be only true or false, than `BIT` should be the choice. Otherwise, you lose a very natural constraint that simply does not let you have invalid values in your column.

SSIS trouble with BIT can be overcome as shown [here](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/ssis-truefalse-and-10-values-on-bit-columns/).

Also, storing BITs may be more efficient (at least one byte must be used to store BIT columns). Check [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3718066/Disk-Space-Usage-and-SQL-Server-Performance.htm) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me the answer I needed

Comment: Quick question, related to this topic, what if in a datawarehouse perspective you want to clean the nulls if the column allows nulls what would be a good replacement value when its neither 0 or 1?

Comment: If a bit is null, how is it treated (what does it mean)? From the business perspective, null means "not determined". From the technical perspective it will generate false for boolean evaluations (usually unwanted).

Answer (score 3):

Personally I have converted a lot of bit columns to `tinyint` and some to `smallint` in my data warehouse to add additional flexibility/cases.

- `BIT` allows for 3 cases (0 false 1 true and NULL unknown)
- `TINYINT` allows for 256 cases (0-255 and NULL)
- `SMALLINT` allows for up to 65,537 cases (-32,768 to 32,767 and NULL)

AS far as storage space `TINYINT` actually wins that one:

- `BIT` 1 Byte storage for upto 8 columns then 2 Bytes when 9 to 16 columns (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx(
- `TINYINT` 1 Byte
- `SMALLINT` 2 Bytes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx)

But all of this depends on the actual use and who will be using/reporting.  If using lookup tables etc. to eliminate nulls in a data warehouse I will go `-1 for unknown` case and reserve `0 for none or not applicable (NA)`.  But I am assuming users when using a cube will not want to see a `1 or 0` but rather `YES or NO`.  However your SQL guru would probably rather see a `BIT` to understand that you mean `YES or NO`.  One added benefit though for SQL guru would be being able to add the integers rather than having to convert the bit first which is nice when doing some bitwise operations.

Bottom line it will depend on your table, your structure, your business case and in some cases it may be appropriate to use an integer and in others to stick with the `BIT`

Answer (score 0):

I like non-nullable bit fields because the content is guaranteed to be true or false.  In other words, it is much harder to load erroneous data.  In my opinion, the extra effort required to populate the fields is a trade-off I'm happy to make.

I also like to partner my bit fields with a text descriptor.  Computed columns can guard against mismatches and mistakes while providing the presentation layer with a value that is more meaningful to the end user.  True/false makes lots of sense to some, but others users better understand open/closed, active/dormant, on/off etc etc.